# How to capture watch folder deletion events

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a file watch directory named FileWatch

```
 C:\Users\MyFolder\FileWatch\Test
```

The **FileWatch** folder is the watch directory. My application is receicing all events which occur below the FileWatch directory.

However if I delete the **FileWatch** folder itself, no file system event is generated.

Is there any way to capture if a user deletes the FileWatch directory itself?

Comment: Add a `FileSystemWatcher` on the parent directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to description of [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class, events are raised when changed/deleted/created/renamed file or directory *in the directory being monitored*.

So, it should not be watching directory itself. It monitors only files and directories *inside* that directory.

Options (as stated before) - watch to directory `C:\Users\MyFolder\FileWatch` instead.

UPDATE:
If you want to watch only for directory `C:\Users\MyFolder\FileWatch\Test` deletion:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\MyFolder\FileWatch"; // watch for parent directory
if (!Directory.Exists(path)) // verify it exists before start
    return;

FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
// set option to track directories only
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

watcher.Deleted += (o, e) =>
{
    if (e.FullPath == @"C:\Users\MyFolder\FileWatch\Test")
    {
        // If you are here, your test directory was deleted
    }
};

watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: Issue is if the folder is C:\FileWatch, then we can't watch the parent folder. Some of the Windows OS, it will allow to delete the above folder of the file watcher.

Comment: Btw you can use `Path.GetDirectoryName(path)` to get parent folder of folder you are watching for.

Comment: ,I tested your code with the folder structure C:\MyFolder, if I delete MyFolder, the delete events are not executed.

Comment: Nope, its working. You should change path to @"C:\" and in event handler check for @"C:\MyFolder" full name. Or use GetDirectoryName as I stated above. Just set the breakpoint on event handler and verify.

Comment: If you try it in ConsoleApplication, keep in mind, that Console.ReadKey() blocks output

Comment: if path = @"C:\"; its working, but the filewatcher will watch all directories under C:\. I think this may cause a performance issue. Please correct me.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you simply watch the *parent* directory instead or you can try using a timer to check if the Directory gets deleted using `Directory.Exists`.

EDIT: If you need to ensure the directory doesn't get deleted, you can create and [lock a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock%28VS.71%29.aspx) inside the directory while you're watching it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, it uses a blocking call and doesn't require an event.

```
using System.IO;

namespace Sapbucket.Common
{
    public static class FolderSupport
    {
        public static void DeleteFolder(string folderPath, bool recursively)
        {
            DirectoryInfo _directoryInfo;

            _directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
            _directoryInfo.Refresh();
            if (_directoryInfo.Exists)
            {
                _directoryInfo.Delete(recursively);

                while (_directoryInfo.Exists)
                    _directoryInfo.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the key is to call Refresh() because someone at Microsoft thought that it would be handy to cache the directory info.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up your `FileWatcher` instance on the `FileWatch` folder, set it up with the parent folder (`MyFolder`). That way, you can trap file events within the `FileWatch` folder, and also the event that is fired when the `FileWatch` folder itself is deleted.

Comment: That's not what you said in your question. Please post the correct file paths.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize that issue. after  teh solution I thought about that.